# Can't delete selected image when update the form by using Yii kartik fileinput

Tags: yii2

I refer to this link https://github.com/jaradsee/faktharm/blob/master/controllers/PhotoLibraryController.php
to upload multiple images but when I try to delete the selected image in update form it showing me these error
([image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHrR8.png))
([image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD3w3.png))

For image 2, why the url link always give products%252Fdeletefile-ajax (give number 25)

Below is my code, please help me to check what's goes wrong, thank you!

**Uploads.php**

```
 class Uploads extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'uploads';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['file_name'], 'required'],
            [['upload_id'], 'integer'],
            [['create_date'], 'safe'],
            [['ref'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['file_name', 'real_filename'], 'string', 'max' => 150],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'upload_id' => 'Upload ID',
            'ref' => 'Ref',
            'file_name' => 'File Name',
            'real_filename' => 'Real Filename',
            'create_date' => 'Create Date',
        ];
    }
}
```

**Products.php**

```
class Products extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */

 //public $file;
    const UPLOAD_FOLDER='products';

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'products';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['productName', 'productDescription', 'productPrice', 'categoryId', 'brandId', 'productStatus'], 'required'],
            [['productDescription', 'productStatus'], 'string'],
            [['productPrice'], 'number'],
            [['categoryId', 'brandId'], 'integer'],
            [['productName','ref'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['brandId'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Brands::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['brandId' => 'brandId']],
            [['categoryId'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Categorys::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['categoryId' => 'categoryId']],
            [['ref'],'unique']
           // ['productImage', 'file','maxFiles'=>5],
           //[['file'],'productImage']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'productId' => 'Product ID',
            'productName' => 'Product Name',
            'productDescription' => 'Product Description',
            'productPrice' => 'Product Price',
            'ref' => 'Product Image',
            'categoryId' => 'Category',
            'brandId' => 'Brand',
            'productStatus' => 'Product Status',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Brand]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getBrand()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Brands::className(), ['brandId' => 'brandId']);
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Category]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Categorys::className(), ['categoryId' => 'categoryId']);
    }

    public function getImages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Images::className(), ['productId' => 'productId']);
    }

    public static function getUploadPath(){
        return Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/'.self::UPLOAD_FOLDER.'/';
    }

    public static function getUploadUrl(){
        return Url::base(true).'/'.self::UPLOAD_FOLDER.'/';
    }

    public function getThumbnails($ref,$event_name){
         $uploadFiles   = Uploads::find()->where(['ref'=>$ref])->all();
         $preview = [];
        foreach ($uploadFiles as $file) {
            $preview[] = [
                'url'=>self::getUploadUrl(true).$ref.'/'.$file->real_filename,
                'src'=>self::getUploadUrl(true).$ref.'/thumbnail/'.$file->real_filename,
                'options' => ['title' => $event_name]
            ];
        }
        return $preview;
    }

}
```

**ProductsController.php**

```
namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use backend\models\Products;
use backend\models\Uploads;
use backend\models\ProductsSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\helpers\Json;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\helpers\html;
use yii\helpers\BaseFileHelper;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

/**
 * ProductsController implements the CRUD actions for Products model.
 */
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
            // 'access' => [
            //     'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            //     'rules' => [
            //         [
            //             'actions' => ['view','update','_form','index','_search','create','uploadAjax','createDir'],
            //             'allow' => true,
            //             'roles' => ['admin'],
            //         ],
            //     ],
            // ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Products models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex($pageSize = 10)
    {
        $searchModel = new ProductsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $pageSize);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'pageSize' => $pageSize,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Products model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Products model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    /*public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Products();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&  $model->save()) {
            
            $model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'productImage');
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->productId]);

        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }*/
 
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Products();
        
       
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
           
            $this->Uploads(false);
            if($model->save()){
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->productId]);    
            }
            
        }
        else{
            $model->ref = substr(Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString(),10);
        }
            
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
           
        ]);
 
    }
 

    /**
     * Updates an existing Products model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        list($initialPreview,$initialPreviewConfig) = $this->getInitialPreview($model->ref);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            
            $this->Uploads(false);

            if($model->save()){
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->productId]);
            }
           
           
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'initialPreview'=>$initialPreview,
            'initialPreviewConfig'=>$initialPreviewConfig
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Products model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        //$model = new Products();

        //$this->findModel($id)->delete();
        $model->$this->findModel($id);

        $this->removeUploadDir($model->ref);
        Uploads::deleteAll(['ref'=>$model->ref]);

        $model->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Products model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Products the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Products::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }

/*|*********************************************************************************|
  |================================ Upload Ajax ====================================|
  |*********************************************************************************|*/

    public function actionUploadAjax(){
        $this->Uploads(true);
    }

    private function CreateDir($folderName){
    if($folderName != NULL){
        $basePath = Products::getUploadPath();
        if(BaseFileHelper::createDirectory($basePath.$folderName,0777)){
            BaseFileHelper::createDirectory($basePath.$folderName.'/thumbnail',0777);
        }
    }
    return;
    }

    private function removeUploadDir($dir){
        BaseFileHelper::removeDirectory(Products::getUploadPath().$dir);
    }

    private function Uploads($isAjax=false) {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
           $images = UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('upload_ajax');
           if ($images) {

               if($isAjax===true){
                   $ref =Yii::$app->request->post('ref');
               }else{
                   $Products = Yii::$app->request->post('Products');
                   $ref = $Products['ref'];
               }
              
               $this->CreateDir($ref);

               foreach ($images as $file){
                   $fileName       = $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
                   $realFileName   = md5($file->baseName.time()) . '.' . $file->extension;
                   $savePath       = Products::UPLOAD_FOLDER.'/'.$ref.'/'. $realFileName;
                   if($file->saveAs($savePath)){

                       if($this->isImage(Url::base(true).'/'.$savePath)){
                            $this->createThumbnail($ref,$realFileName);
                       }
                     
                       $model                  = new Uploads;
                       $model->ref             = $ref;
                       $model->file_name       = $fileName;
                       $model->real_filename   = $realFileName;
                       $model->save();

                       if($isAjax===true){
                           echo json_encode(['success' => 'true']);
                       }
                       
                   }else{
                       if($isAjax===true){
                           echo json_encode(['success'=>'false','eror'=>$file->error]);
                       }
                   }
                   
               }
           }
       }
    }

    private function getInitialPreview($ref) {
        $datas = Uploads::find()->where(['ref'=>$ref])->all();
        $initialPreview = [];
        $initialPreviewConfig = [];
        foreach ($datas as $key => $value) {
            array_push($initialPreview, $this->getTemplatePreview($value));
            array_push($initialPreviewConfig, [
                'caption'=> $value->file_name,
                'width'  => '120px',
                'url'    => Url::to(['/products/deletefile-ajax']),
                'key'    => $value->upload_id
            ]);
        }
        return  [$initialPreview,$initialPreviewConfig];
    }

    public function isImage($filePath){
        return @is_array(getimagesize($filePath)) ? true : false;
    }

    private function getTemplatePreview(Uploads $model){     
        $filePath = Products::getUploadUrl().$model->ref.'/thumbnail/'.$model->real_filename;
        $isImage  = $this->isImage($filePath);
        if($isImage){
            $file = Html::img($filePath,['class'=>'file-preview-image', 'alt'=>$model->file_name, 'title'=>$model->file_name]);
        }else{
            $file =  "<div class='file-preview-other'> " .
                     "<h2><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'></i></h2>" .
                     "</div>";
        }
        return $file;
    }

    private function createThumbnail($folderName,$fileName,$width=250){
        $uploadPath   = Products::getUploadPath().'/'.$folderName.'/'; 
        $file         = $uploadPath.$fileName;
        $image        = Yii::$app->image->load($file);
        $image->resize($width);
        $image->save($uploadPath.'thumbnail/'.$fileName);
        return;
    }

    public function actionDeletefileAjax(){

        $model = Uploads::findOne(Yii::$app->request->post('key'));
        if($model!==NULL){
            $filename  = Products::getUploadPath().$model->ref.'/'.$model->real_filename;
            $thumbnail = Products::getUploadPath().$model->ref.'/thumbnail/'.$model->real_filename;
            if($model->delete()){
                @unlink($filename);
                @unlink($thumbnail);
                echo json_encode(['success'=>true]);
            }else{
                echo json_encode(['success'=>false]);
            }
        }else{
          echo json_encode(['success'=>false]);  
        }
    }

}
```

**_form.php**

```
<?php
//use kartik\file\FileInput;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use backend\models\Brands;
use backend\models\Categorys;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use kartik\file\FileInput;



/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\Products */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="photo-library-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

    <?php $form->errorSummary($model) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ref')->hiddenInput(['maxlength' => 100])->label(false); ?>
    
    <?= $form->field($model, 'productName')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'productDescription')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'productPrice')->textInput() ?>

    <?= 
        $form->field($model, 'brandId')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' =>  ArrayHelper::map(Brands::find()->where(['brandStatus'=>'active'])->all(),'brandId','brandName'),
        'language' => 'en',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a brand ...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
        ]);
    ?>
    
    <?= 
        $form->field($model, 'categoryId')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' =>  ArrayHelper::map(Categorys::find()->where(['categoryStatus'=>'active'])->all(),'categoryId','categoryName'),
        'language' => 'en',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a category ...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
        ]);
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'productStatus')->dropDownList([ 'active' => 'Active', 'inactive' => 'Inactive', ], ['prompt' => 'Status']) ?>
    
  
    <div class="form-group field-upload_files">
      <label class="control-label" for="upload_files[]"> Product Images </label>
    <div>
   
    <?=

        FileInput::widget([
        'name' => 'upload_ajax[]',
        //'attribute'=>'productImage[]',
        //'name'=>'productImage[]',
        'options' => [
            'multiple'=>true,
            'accept' => 'image/*',
            //'id'=>'imageId',
        ],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            
            'initialPreview'=> $initialPreview,
            'initialPreviewConfig'=> $initialPreviewConfig,
            'deleteUrl'=>Url::to(['/products/deletefile-ajax']),
            'showPreview' => true,
            'showCaption' => false,
            'showRemove' => false,
            'showUpload' => false,
            'uploadAsync' => true,
            'uploadUrl'=>Url::to(['/products/upload-ajax']),
            'maxFileCount' => 5,
            'allowedFileExtensions' => ['jpg', 'png','jpeg'],
            'previewFileType' => ['jpg', 'png','jpeg'],
            'overwriteInitial'=>false,
             'uploadExtraData' => [
                 'ref'=>$model->ref
             ],
             
            
            'msgUploadBegin' => Yii::t('app', 'Please wait, system is uploading the files'),
            'validateInitailCount'=>true,
            'layoutTemplates'=>[
                  'actionZoom'=>'<button type="button" class="kv-file-zoom">{zoomIcon}</button>',
                  'actionUpload'=>'',
                  //'actionDelete'=>'<a>jj</a>',
                  //'footer' => '<div class="file-thumbnail-footer"><div class="file-caption-name" style="width:{width}">{caption}{size}</div>
                  //{progress}{actions}',
                  //'footer' => '<div class="file-thumbnail-footer"> <div class="file-caption-caption" title="{caption}"</div>'
                  //'actionDelete'=>'<button type="button" class="kv-file-remove"> {dataKey}{deleteUrl} {removeIcon}</button>',
                
              ],
              
            ],
            'pluginEvents' => [
                'filebatchselected' => 'function(event, files) {
                    $(this).fileinput("/products/upload-ajax");
      
                    }',
            ],
            
 
            
            
    ]);
  
  ?>
  
    <br>
   
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord? 'Save': 'Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Cancel'), ['index', 'id' => $model->productId], ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: %2f is the url encoding of /, if you have %252f seems a double encode of the specific string, maybe this is the error

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution my bad
need to change all the Url::to() in controller and _form
to this format [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evolp.png)

Comment: Please post a detailed answer

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

The detail answer as below

**_form.php**

```
<?php
//use kartik\file\FileInput;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use backend\models\Brands;
use backend\models\Categorys;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use kartik\file\FileInput;



/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\Products */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="photo-library-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

    <?php $form->errorSummary($model) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'ref')->hiddenInput(['maxlength' => 100])->label(false); ?>
    
    <?= $form->field($model, 'productName')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'productDescription')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'productPrice')->textInput() ?>

    <?= 
        $form->field($model, 'brandId')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' =>  ArrayHelper::map(Brands::find()->where(['brandStatus'=>'active'])->all(),'brandId','brandName'),
        'language' => 'en',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a brand ...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
        ]);
    ?>
    
    <?= 
        $form->field($model, 'categoryId')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
        'data' =>  ArrayHelper::map(Categorys::find()->where(['categoryStatus'=>'active'])->all(),'categoryId','categoryName'),
        'language' => 'en',
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a category ...'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true
        ],
        ]);
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'productStatus')->dropDownList([ 'active' => 'Active', 'inactive' => 'Inactive', ], ['prompt' => 'Status']) ?>
    
  
   <label>Product Images</label>
   
    <?=

        FileInput::widget([
        'name' => 'upload_ajax[]',
        //'attribute'=>'productImage[]',
        //'name'=>'productImage[]',
        'options' => [
            'multiple'=>true,
            'accept' => 'image/*',
            //'id'=>'imageId',
        ],
        
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'initialPreview'=> $initialPreview,
            'initialPreviewConfig'=> $initialPreviewConfig,
            'showPreview' => true,
            'showCaption' => false,
            'showRemove' => false,
            'showUpload' => false,
            'uploadAsync' => false,
            'uploadUrl'=>Url::to('index.php?r=products/upload-ajax'),
            'deleteUrl'=>Url::to('index.php?r=products/deletefile-ajax'),
            'maxFileCount' => 5,
            'allowedFileExtensions' => ['jpg', 'png','jpeg'],
            'previewFileType' => ['jpg', 'png','jpeg'],
            'overwriteInitial'=>false,
            'enableResumableUpload'=>true,
            'uploadExtraData' => [
                 'ref'=>$model->ref
            ], 
            'validateInitialCount'=>true,
            'initialPreviewShowDelete' => true, 
            'layoutTemplates'=>[
                  'actionZoom'=>'<button type="button" class="kv-file-zoom">{zoomIcon}</button>',
                  'actionUpload'=>'',
                  'actionDelete' => '<button type="button" class="kv-file-remove" title="{removeTitle}" {dataKey}{dataUrl}><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>'
                    
              ],
              
            ],
             'pluginEvents' => [
                // 'filebatchselected' => 'function(files) {
                //      $(this).fileinput("index.php?r=products/upload-ajax");
      
                // }',
               'filepredelete'=>'function(jqXHR){
                var abort = true;
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this image?")) {
                    abort = false;
                }
                return abort;
               }'
             ],    
    ]);
  
  ?>
  
    <br>
   
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord? 'Save': 'Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Cancel'), ['index', 'id' => $model->productId], ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

**ProductsController**

```
 private function getInitialPreview($ref) {
        $datas = Uploads::find()->where(['ref'=>$ref])->all();
        $initialPreview = [];
        $initialPreviewConfig = [];
        foreach ($datas as $key => $value) {
            array_push($initialPreview, $this->getTemplatePreview($value));
            array_push($initialPreviewConfig, [
                'caption'=> $value->file_name,
                'width'  => '120px',
                'url'    => Url::to('index.php?r=products/deletefile-ajax'),
                'key'    => $value->upload_id
            ]);
        }
        return  [$initialPreview,$initialPreviewConfig];
    }
```